# Make NESTED tkinter frame widgets look like one frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, overlay

Is there a simple way to get **nested** frames to look like one frame - preferably using the grid layout manager?  This is relatively easy to do when the frames are *not* nested (i.e. the frames are children of the *same* parent widget - see second image).
The problem is the (1 pixel?) separation that appears between the 
frames.  Eliminate that and my problem disappears.

In the first image the three vertical lines, the edge boundaries of the nested frames, need to appear as one line (the same thing applies to the horizontal lines at the bottom of the image).  The desired result is a (parent) frame that contains 3 (child) frames - the second image.

I have these **nested** frames :  [image: Merge these tkinter frame boundaries]  but need them to look like :    [image: Combined tkinter Frame Boundaries]

BTW, all three child frames were implemented as Frame, not Button widgets.

I've tried playing around with the "padx" (zero and negative numbers), "relief" (set to FLAT, etc.), and borderwidth (set to 0 and -1) widget properites without success.

I'm reluctant to re-engineer the app (to use Canvas and/or ttk.Separator) just to fix this small but annoying issue.  And eliminating the nesting is NOT an acceptable approach (unless there's absolutely no other way).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us a [mcve] so we can play with it. I'm guessing the easiest solution will be to make a function to convert from nested to sequential.

Comment: What do you mean by nested exactly? What's the kind of nesting that you don't want to eliminate unless there's absolutely no other way?

Comment: Frame A contains Frame B which contains Frame C. Complexity is managed by placing each frame in it's own (nested) function.  "Unnesting" destroys the modularity/isolaton enforced by this structure, making the code harder to maintain (you go from a clean structure to a messy one). The screenshots are extremely simplifed versions of what's in each frame which is why easy maintenance/modification is a basic requirement (e.g. you can move a child frame to a different parent just by moving the function call to the new parent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the borderwidths of the inner frames to zero and then separating them with a `ttk.Separator` gives you the look you want.

[image]

Code that produced the above image:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("250x200")

outer_frame = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
outer_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

f1 = tk.Frame(outer_frame, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
f2 = tk.Frame(outer_frame, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
f3 = tk.Frame(outer_frame, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)

tk.Label(f1, text="Child Frame 1").pack(fill="both", expand=True)
tk.Label(f2, text="Child Frame 2").pack(fill="both", expand=True)
tk.Label(f3, text="Child Frame 3").pack(fill="both", expand=True)

s1 = ttk.Separator(outer_frame, orient="horizontal")
s2 = ttk.Separator(outer_frame, orient="horizontal")

f1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
s1.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
f2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
s2.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
f3.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It looks like I can't do what I want using only the basic tkinter widgets. I got too fixated on using .grid - the key is to use .pack when inserting the child frames into the parent frame,

Comment: @user1459519: it depends on what you mean by "only the basic tkinter widgets". I don't see how ttk is any less "basic". Also, you can use either `grid` or `pack` (or even `place`) to get the same effect. I just used `pack` for the example because it requires fewer lines of code, and is arguably the right choice when stacking things top-to-bottom.

Comment: By basic I meant only using "from tkinter import * " line. 
I got it to work using grid. My problem was getting the proper combinaton of  "'grid parameters" (e.g. columnconfigure(), rowconfigure(), padx, pady, sticky, etc.) set properly on ALL of the widgets.  BTW, it should be trivial for the standard widgets to show 1 pixel borders WITHOUT the annoying 3-D shadow coloring. The best I've come up with is setting relief = RIDGE and borderwidth = 1 but that doesn't seem to work on all widgets.  Surely I don't have to use ttk.separtor and "roll my own" versions of the standard widgets?

Comment: @user1459519: setting relief to solid and a borderwidth of 1 should give you a one pixel border. If the borderwidth is 1, it's impossible for it to appear as a 3D object with a shadow. You also have the option of a one pixel tall canvas that you can assign any color you want.